# SQL/Oracle Joining Multiple Functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which gives me a result of actions. Now, what I want to do is split this result into 2 parts, for 2 separate groups of users I have...

```
Select Sum(Actions) From
(
Select
Count(Create_Dtime) As Actions
From Player_Tapjoy
Where
Trunc(Create_Dtime) = To_Date('2012-sep-12','yyyy-mon-dd')
Union All
Select 
Count(Create_Dtime) As Actions
From Player_aux_pt
Where Site = 'AppCircle' And
Trunc(Create_Dtime) = To_Date('2012-sep-12','yyyy-mon-dd')
);
```

Both tables in the current query have player_id tags. There is another table called player_source where I have group IDs (1-100) for each player_id. I want to map the current query to the player_source table by player_id so that I can only include specific group_ids  (say 1,2,3,4 and 6). Any suggestions?

The IDs that I want to include in my first query come from the query:

```
Select Player_Id From Player_Source S Inner Join Feature_Group_Xref F 
On S.Group_Id=F.Group_Id
where f.feature_name = 'BC'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to only include specific group IDs, and the player_source table has the Group ID, you need to join the player_source table to the "main" tables - tapjoy and aux_pt.  You have to do it on each component of the UNION since you are aggregating the results and won't be able to filter individual records after aggregation.  You provided the query to get the group_ids, so inner joins are all that was needed to get from tapjoy/aux_pt to feature_group_xref.

Here's the result:

```
Select Sum(Actions) From
(
Select
Count(t.Create_Dtime) As Actions
From Player_Tapjoy t inner join player_source s on (t.player_id = s.player_id)
Inner Join Feature_Group_Xref F On (S.Group_Id=F.Group_Id and f.feature_name = 'BC')
Where Trunc(t.Create_Dtime) = To_Date('2012-sep-12','yyyy-mon-dd')
Union All
Select 
Count(a.Create_Dtime) As Actions
From Player_aux_pt a inner join player_source s on (a.player_id = s.player_id)
Inner Join Feature_Group_Xref F On (S.Group_Id=F.Group_Id and f.feature_name = 'BC')
Where a.Site = 'AppCircle' And
Trunc(a.Create_Dtime) = To_Date('2012-sep-12','yyyy-mon-dd')
)
```

Comment: This worked great!thank you...if you have time could you provide a brief explanation why you added what you did? That way next time i wont have to ask a similar question :)

Comment: Sure, I added some detail, hope that helps!